# How to alter views exposed form and add ajax to filters

Tags: 8, ajax, views, forms

I have a views with 2 exposed filters - both taxonomy reference, select. 
I want to limit options in second filter based on user selection from the first. Tested with enabled/disabled ajax in views - no difference. Tested with exposed form in block - no difference.

Error message replace target filter: **"An unrecoverable error occurred. The uploaded file likely exceeded the maximum file size (60 MB) that this server supports."**

Using standard form alteration and ajax in form exposed filters, the filtering produce error. This work fine in custom form, but not in views exposed filter.

```
<?php

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {  
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {
    if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-articles-page-1') {
      //kint($form);
      //kint($form_state);
      //
      $form['field_tags2_target_id']['#prefix'] = '<div id="tags2-replace">';
      $form['field_tags2_target_id']['#suffix'] = '</div>';

      $form['field_tags_target_id']['#ajax'] = [
        'callback' => 'tags_ajax_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'tags2-replace'
      ];
    }
  }
}

function tags_ajax_callback($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // remove test2 1 (tid 3) from Tags2 options
  unset($form['field_tags2_target_id']['#options'][3]);

  $response = new AjaxResponse();
  $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand(
    '#tags2-replace',
    $form['field_tags2_target_id']
  ));
  return $response;

  //return $form['field_tags2_target_id'];
}
```

How to make this work?

Comment: core issue for this found here https://www.drupal.org/node/2842525

Answer (score 1):

It is related to [Ajax attached to Views exposed filter form does not trigger callbacks](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2842525) where [2842525-56.patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2019-08-01/2842525-56.patch) is the patch provided for that issue on August first, 2019; further patches have been provided for other Drupal releases.

Comment: Hello This patch worked for apache server but issue still occur for nginx server
drupal version- 8.6.13
php version - 7.1.25

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to patch the core you can create an `EventSubscriber` that attaches the view filter to the ajax command. After adding this your can use `hook_form_alter` to alter the filter. The subscriber looks like this.

file: `yourmodule.services.yml`

```yml
services:
  yourmodule.ajax_respose_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\yourmodule\EventSubscriber\AjaxResponseSubscriber
    tags:
      - {name: event_subscriber}
```

file: `src/EventSubscriber/AjaxResponseSubscriber.php`

```php
<?php

namespace Drupal\yourmodule\EventSubscriber;

use Drupal\views\Ajax\ViewAjaxResponse;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\ReplaceCommand;

/**
 * Response subscriber to handle AJAX responses.
 */
class AjaxResponseSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  /**
   * Renders the ajax commands right before preparing the result.
   *
   * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent $event
   *   The response event, which contains the possible AjaxResponse object.
   */
  public function onResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event) {
    $response = $event->getResponse();

    // Only alter views ajax responses.
    if (!($response instanceof ViewAjaxResponse)) {
      return;
    }
    $view = $response->getView();

    // Only alter commands if view is ours.
    if ($view->storage->id() != 'yourviewname') {
      return;
    }

    // Alter commands.
    $display_handler = $view->display_handler;
    if ($display_handler->ajaxEnabled() && $display_handler->usesExposedFormInBlock()) {
      $form = $display_handler->viewExposedFormBlocks();
      $rendered_form = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($form);
      $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand("#{$form['#id']}", $rendered_form));
    }

  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    return [KernelEvents::RESPONSE => [['onResponse']]];
  }

}
```

Sources: [1](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3090504#comment-13327318) & [2](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-alter-ajax-commands-view-response-drupal-8-dalibor-stojakovic/)